# How can I embed a react component in HTML (article body)?

Tags: html, reactjs, blogs

I'm developing a blog using react, the articles body are saved in database as HTML (hundred of articles ) so I basically fetch the data and use `<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: data.body}}></div>`.

Which is kinda fine till the client wanted to show a `<Slider />` or any other component in the middle of the article body.

My current approach is:

1. The Editors can type a code `[slider][/slider]` in any part of the article body
2. At the front end, I replace each code with the corresponding component

```
 function ReplaceCodesWithComponents({body}) {

  return body.replace(/\[.+?\]\[\/\w+?\]/g, (code) => {

    // code=[slider][/slider]
    let extractedType = code.match(/(?<=\[\/)\w+(?=\])/g);
  
    if (!extractedType) {
      return code;
    }

    // ["slider"]
    extractedType = extractedType[0];

    // "slider"
    switch (extractedType) {
      case "slider":
        return <Slider />;   // this doesn't work 
      case "products":
        return <Products />;  // this doesn't work 
      case "gallery":
        return <Gallery />;  // this doesn't work  
      default:
        return "";
    }
  });
}
```

How can I achieve something like that?
Or is that even a good approach?

And if it's a good approach, is it good to perform this process when saving the article in the database?
Or perform it every time when a user visit the article?

Comment: The problem is that you save HTML in your database as opposed to structural data. This introduces security issues and scalability ones as you are finding out yourself now. I would try to convert the HTML somehow and go from there as your problems will only get harder. If that's not an option then I would SSR your react component and use common HTML parsing libs to make changes.

Comment: yeah im using Nextjs to statically render all pages. would i still need to convert them in the database ?